# How do I use an Arduino as a USB output device for a 2x16 display?

Tags: display

Can I make a USB 2x16 display using an Arduino?
I want to control a 2x16 character lcd display using USB, not com port/serial.

I need it to appear as a HID device when connected to the computer.

Please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of HID device do you think it should be? HID devices are inputs to a computer, not outputs (in general).

Comment: Why do you not want it to appear as Serial? USB HID are much harder to interact with than a simple Serial device. Using Python, you could easily write a program to interact with the device.

Comment: I want to make a simple USB 2x16 lcd display device using Arduino, something which we can plug into the USB and use for displaying any message like a plug and play 2x16 lcd display.

Comment: If you truly want to make this a USB HID device and not the usual USB serial one, you should probably look at a board such as the Leonardo or Due or Teensy or Feather M0 where the USB is directly handled by the application processor, or else look into reprogramming the ATmega16u2 on an Uno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HID's generally are input devices to your computer, if you do want your computer to send data to the device you will need an application to do it.

So your best bet is to have a windows app to communicate with your arduino using a virtual com port ( as it does already) and send data as you require

Comment: HID can be used for data to the device as well, it simply isn't specialized for it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes you are right, which is why i was careful enough to use the word **generally** :)

Comment: So, if it is possible use it as a HID output device, are there any chances for me to make a USB 2X16 lcd display device using Arduino?

Comment: @Josh what do you mean by HID output device?

output for the computer?

Comment: Yes, output strings from the computer to display on the 2x16 lcd by making it a HID device. How to achieve this?

Comment: From what I know your best bet is to create a simple python program to send the required data to your arduino and then the arduino receives, processes the data and displays the data on the screen. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/635papy9py7jjvp/serial_arduino.py?dl=0

This sample code is used to turn on/off the led at pin 13, i.e. if I receive 'h' turn led on, if i receive 'l' turn led off

Comment: This still needs com port configuration. I want to make a simple Plug N Play device using Arduino just like any usb keyboard,mouse, pen drives which require no com port configurations. We don't select COM3/COM5 when we use usb devices. I want to make a normal usb device which can be used.

Comment: Yes. please understand that irrespective of whether you use a virtual com port or not, you will need to write your own application in order for your computer to communicate with the arduino. If you want to do it in HID mode, you may need to create your own [drivers] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208215/what-data-can-a-hid-device-receive) and modify the arduino library. So your best option is to use it in virtual com port mode, create a python app similar to that in the link i had shown earlier, it will be much easier as well as portable

Comment: @josh There wont be a need to configure the com port, you can just scan the current options and get your program to do the rest (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090503/listing-available-com-ports-with-python)

Comment: HID doesn't require a specific driver (or rather, all USB-capable OSes already have a generic HID driver), simply a program that talks to the HID susbsystem.

Comment: @evolutionizer I don't mind writing my own program in Python / C#. As long as it's not very complex code, it's ok. Scanning com ports is certainly an option but it will be slow and could make the user wait on Windows. That's why, I want to develop a plug n play device that just works seamlessly.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So, if all OS's have a built-in HID driver, how do I communicate to Arduino over HID to send data using Python/C#? I have only seen arduino HID input devices like keyboard,mouse. Are there any examples of the pin connections & sample program for sending strings out to arduino from PC using HID?

Comment: @Josh: V-USB has several command line programs that show interacting with the HID driver.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Do you mean that I need to use COM ports even if Arduino acts as a HID device? You mean HID does not replace COM ports?

Comment: No. You access the HID driver.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just googled about V-USB. Sorry, didn't know it  was related to micro controller.I thought you V-USB meant serial